# index of $Z\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p>2$, consider the subgroup $Z\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ where $Z\cong\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$ is the centre of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Then I'd like to know how to prove that the index of $Z\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is $4$.

By the determinant map, I know that there is an isomorphism of groups $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)\cong\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$. But I do know how to continue.

The motivation is that I want to know the dimension of the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}_{Z\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)}^{\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)}$ of a character.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I suspect again that some of the people voting to close have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: @DerekHolt: That might be true, but isn't that irrelevant? (I neither downvoted nor voted to close, and do find the close votes hasty, but I would like to see the question improved by inserting some motivation, context, and most importantly attempts or at least thoughts.)

Comment: @Jean Thanks for editing the question. Well, the determinant of everything in your group is a square, right ...? What else has index $4$ for odd $p$ and is related to squares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you observe, determinant gives an isomorphism $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)\simeq\mathbb Q_p^\times$. There is an isomorphism
$$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)/Z\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)\simeq\mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2.$$
There is moreover a short exact sequence
$$1\to\mathbb Z_p^\times\to\mathbb Q_p^\times\xrightarrow v\mathbb Z\to 0,$$
which upon tensoring with $\mathbb Z/2$ (since $\mathbb Z$ is free) induces a short exact sequence
$$1\to\mathbb Z_p^\times/(\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2\to\mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2\to\mathbb Z/2\to 0.$$
Since $\mathbb Z_p^\times/(\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2\simeq\mathbb F_p^\times/(\mathbb F_p^\times)^2$ has order $2$ (since $\mathbb F_p^\times$ is cyclic), this shows $\mathbb Q_p^\times/(\mathbb Q_p^\times)^2$ has order $4$, so the index of $Z\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)\subset \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Q_p)$ is $4$.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify exactly where you use $p \neq 2$ (you know of course, but readers might not).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg good idea, when $p=2$, the isomorphism $\mathbb Z_p^\times/(\mathbb Z_p^\times)^2\simeq\mathbb F_p^\times/(\mathbb F_p^\times)^2$ fails.